# "Compile Error: Else without if" in VBA, can't find what it's talking about

Tags: vba, excel

I don't have much experience at all with VBA, and am trying to write a backend function to tally up certain fields depending on the value of another field. I have a bunch of nested If Then and ElseIf Then statements, and am getting the error on my first ElseIf. Here's the block in question:

```
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Blueprint" Then
    aCell = Range("DR")
    If aCell.Value = "Yes" Then
        aCell = Range("ER")
            If aCell.Value = "Yes" Then
              PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
             End If
            ElseIf aCell.Value = "No" Or aCell.Value = "N/A" Or aCell.Value = "Unknown" Then
                PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
         End If
    ElseIf aCell.Value = "No" Or aCell.Value = "N/A" Or aCell.Value = "Unknown" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
```

Most of the solutions I've found to this problem involve indenting after every Then or making sure there's enough End Ifs, but I've done that and the problem persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 2: Problem has been solved, just tinkered with End Ifs until it worked. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: You have an `End If` which is termination that if statement before the ElseIf which is causing the problem.  Delete the `End If` line that follows `PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True`

Comment: Put another`End If` after the last `End If` or show the whole `If.... end if` code

Comment: Learn to indent your code and you will avoid these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each ElseIf does not get its own `End If`

Also proper indentation helps find these problems.

The proper method is:

```
IF ... Then
    'do somthing
ElseIf
    'do somthing
Else
    'do somthing
End If
```

With the `ElseIf` and `Else` being optional.

```
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Blueprint" Then
    aCell = Range("DR")
    If aCell.Value = "Yes" Then
        aCell = Range("ER")
        If aCell.Value = "Yes" Then
            PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
        ElseIf aCell.Value = "No" Or aCell.Value = "N/A" Or aCell.Value = "Unknown" Then
            PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
        End If
    ElseIf aCell.Value = "No" Or aCell.Value = "N/A" Or aCell.Value = "Unknown" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
End If
```

Here is your long nested ifs, simplified with `And`s

```
Public Function PHASEREVIEWCHECKER(R As Integer)
Dim rCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set rCell = Range("CR")
If rCell.Value = "Initiate" Then
    If Range("DR").Value = "Yes" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
    Else
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Blueprint" Then
    If Range("DR").Value = "Yes" And Range("ER") = "Yes" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
    Else
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Design" Then
    If Range("DR").Value = "Yes" And Range("ER").Value = "Yes" And Range("FR").Value = "Yes" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
    Else
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Build" Then
    If Range("DR").Value = "Yes" And Range("ER").Value = "Yes" And Range("FR").Value = "Yes" And Range("GR").Value = "Yes" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
    Else
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Test & Train" Then
    If Range("DR").Value = "Yes" And Range("ER").Value = "Yes" And Range("FR").Value = "Yes" And Range("GR").Value = "Yes" _
        And Range("HR").Value = "Yes" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
    Else
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
ElseIf rCell.Value = "Deploy & Operate" Then
    If Range("DR").Value = "Yes" And Range("ER").Value = "Yes" And Range("FR").Value = "Yes" And Range("GR").Value = "Yes" _
        And Range("HR").Value = "Yes" And Range("IR").Value = "Yes" Then
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = True
    Else
        PHASEREVIEWCHECKER = False
    End If
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is giving me the same error

Comment: Then you need to show the entire IF statement, because the error is there and not on the snippet I edited for you.